# Flex C++ print code in generated file and add color

Tags: c++, c, lex, lexical-analysis, flex++

I'm trying to insert the code that flex reads into my .tex file, this console app is supposed to take a .pascal and analyze it and then generate a .tex file but I'm not able to pass the code to the .tex file and then I need to add color to each token it reads, I need help!!
Commands to compile it  flex file.l, g++ lex.yy.c, ./a.out,  test.pascal, pdflatex PDF.tex

```
%{ 
#include <iostream>   
#include <fstream>   
#include <string>   
using namespace std;   

int token_if = 0;   
%}


%%

if  ++token_if;
then|begin|end|procedure|function        {
                printf( "A keyword: %s\n", yytext );
                }
%%

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{

    //read file
    FILE *fp;
    char filename[50], c;
    printf("Enter the filename: \n");
    scanf("%s",filename);
    fp = fopen(filename,"r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("file null");
        exit(0);
    } else 
    {
    yyin = fp;
    //start of lex
    yylex();    
    
    // counter
    //get_token(token_if);
    
    //create latex file
    ofstream myPDF("PDF.tex");

    myPDF  << " \\documentclass{article} "
            << "\\title{Scanner}"
            << "\\author{Andres}"
            << "\\date{III}"
            << " \\begin{document} "
            << "\\maketitle"
            << "\\newpage"
            << "\\section{¿Q?}"
            << " number of if's " 
            << token_if
            << " \\end{document} ";

        myPDF.close();

    }

    // printf("# of if's = %d",  token_if);   

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I wanted to fix the language tags but after seeing the code, they look accurate ;-) The Lex part seem to be more C and the rest more C++. Does this even compile? Have you set Lex to compile for C++? I suppose this could work then.

Comment: What is the exact problem, you're asking about. Does this code compile? If not, what's the error? If yes, how the result differs from the expectations?

Comment: yes these are the commands to compile it, flex file.l, g++ lex.yy.c, ./a.out you enter a file like test.pascal then just do this command pdflatex PDF.tex and it creates the LaTex file

Comment: How can I add the code that I'm reading to my pdf, I tried changing this part 
    FILE *fp;
    char filename[50];
    printf("Enter the filename: \n");
    scanf("%s",filename);
    fp = fopen(filename,"r"); 
to C++ but can't seem to do it because it's affecting the yyin = fp, I saw that I can just take the ifstream and add it to the of stream like in this example https://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/158251-getting-data-from-one-file-to-another-file-using-c/#:~:text=open%20a%20file%20for%20writing

Answer (score 0):

1. (F)lex is design to split an input into a sequence of tokens. Every character in the input will be part of some identified token. What you do with the tokens is up to --you can just ignore them, if they don't interest you-- but (F)lex will still recognize them.

   A pattern list like the one you show obviously doesn't satisfy this requirement. By default, if you give (F)lex a non-exhaustive set of patterns, it adds a fallback pattern at the end, which matches any single character, and assigns it the default action, which is to send the character to `yyout` (by default, `stdout`). That's not usually what is wanted, and it's definitely not what you want.

   There is no (F)lex configuration option which changes the default action. All you can do is ensure that it never triggers, by giving (F)lex a set of patterns which is guaranteed to never fall through. You can tell Flex that you don't want its default pattern (using `%option nodefault`); if you do that and your patterns are not exhaustive, then Flex will produce a warning, and the scanner will immediately terminate if it can't match at some point in the scan.

   `%option nodefault` is highly recommended, precisely because the default action is so rarely desired. If you use that option, you will need to ensure that your patterns are complete; the simplest way to do that is to put your own fallback pattern at the end of your pattern list, with whatever action seems appropriate. If, as I suppose is the case here, you don't want to do anything with the token, you can use an action like `{ }` or `;`:

   ```
   .|\n        ;
   ```
2. Note that (F)lex doesn't make any assumptions about your input patterns. It does not, for example, assume that you want to ignore whitespace (maybe you don't), nor does it assume that you are only interested in the string `if` as a complete word. All of that is up to you. Your patters, as written, will happily recognise `Eiffel` and `semifredo` as instances of a Pascal conditional. That's surely not what you want, and I suspect you also don't want to recognise `if` when it is in a comment or a string literal. So you still have quite a bit of work to do on your patterns. (The usual solution to matching keywords only when they are complete words is to also match complete words, using a pattern like `[[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]]*`. That pattern goes after all the keyword patterns, so it will trigger if the token *starts* with a keyword (because (F)lex always chooses the longest match at each point in the input) but won't match if the token is precisely the keyword (because Flex always chooses the first of the patterns which match the same longest token.)
   It's worth reading at least two sections of the [Flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/): [Patterns](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Patterns.html) and [How the input is matched](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Matching.html).
3. If I undertand correctly what you are looking for, you want to know how to dump the input to a file while Flex is working on it. One obvious way would be to write each token to the file as you recognise it, which means adding boilerplate code to every action (even the actions which do nothing.) If what you are trying to do is colour-code each token, that's what you will have to do.

   If you just want to copy the parsed file to the output, all that boilerplate is a bit tedious, so you would probably be better off using the [`YY_USER_ACTION` macro](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Misc-Macros.html), which is implicitly expanded at the beginning of every rule action (even for rules with empty actions). Note that you will have to open the output file before you call `yylex`, and also write out whatever codes you need to precede the program text.
   Instead of writing out each token, you could choose to copy the file as it is being read by Flex. To do that, you'll need to define the [`YY_INPUT` macro](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Generated-Scanner.html#index-YY_005fINPUT_002c-overriding). (There is some example code in the linked manual section.)

Comment: Thank you for your response, All I want to do is take the input file which is a pascal file and add it to the output file which is a .tex file with each token colored

Comment: @AIAM2601: so you'll have to write each token (wirh the correct colour commands) in the corresponding rule action, as I say in point 3.

Comment: I understand that, but how can I add the pascal file to my .tex file?

Comment: @AIAM2601: While the rule's action is being executed, the string matched by the pattern is found in `yytext` (which is a NUL-terminated character array, aka a C-string). You can write that to the .tex file the same way you write anything else to the .tex file (`myPDF << yytext;` }, but of course you need to already have `myPDF` opened and initialised *before* you call `yylex`. (And `myPDF` has to be available in `yylex`, which in the simple case means it has to be a global variable.)

Comment: You can change the prototype for `yylex`, which would let you pass `myPDF` as an argument. How to do that is explained in the Flex manual (`YY_DECL`). But my advice is to get it working first, and then make it prettier. My sense is that you have not very much experience in C++, and it can be a bit confusing to try to learn how to use a code generator like Flex *at the same time* as trying to learn the base language. So take it in small steps.

Comment: @AIAM2601: If I've misunderstood your doubt, I apologise. Perhaps you could try explaining why you think writing to the output file is difficult. (Si hay problema de lenguaje, podrías poner la pregunta en [es.so].)

Comment: This is my first project in c++ for school, and I just don't know how to write in the output file the input file(pascal), I'm gonna try what u said